# Internal test track - cannot download the latest release

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have updated 3 APK releases to Internal test track. I thought the updates on the Internal test track were supposed to be immediate.

After the third release, history shows 2 releases, and when I try to download the app on the Play Store using the test link, I only see the first release.

Rollout history Today, 2:55 PM: Full rollout. It's almost 2 hours, and I don't see the last release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it must have been a problem with the servers on that particular day. I have released multiple times to Internal Track after that, and no problems happened.